# Convert cURL command to cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "authorization: <API token>" "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/locations"
```

^  That's the cURL command I want to convert. I tried looking for tutorials on cURL but couldn't understand it. Current code I tried is as follows:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans/%2399VY9JR8');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('authorization: myToken','Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Trying to achieve getting response from API and posting then reading them here.

Answer (score 0):

In get request you just have to pass the params with the URL itself, following code should work:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.clashofclans.com";
$clansId= "2399VY9JR8";
$headers= array("authorization: myToken");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'clans/'.$clansId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Still nothing. Can you head over to developer.clashofclans.com and try and do a request.